# Ansible: How to use split strings based on a delimiter(.) using maps for items present in list

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

In ansible if there is list of host names with fully qualified domain name:

```
 "groups[group_names[0]]": [
        "node1.in.labs.corp.netin",
        "node2.in.labs.corp.netin"
    ]
```

How to obtain only node names from these strings?  Say , answer list should have only these entries:

[node1 , node2]

Tried using map and split operation, But it does not seem to work.It fails saying split operation is not defined for map.

```
msg={{ groups[group_names[0]] | map('split','@') | flatten }}
```

Is there any other way ? Thank you in advance.

---

I tried using regex_replace option this way:

Here groups[group_names[0]] is list of node names

```
 "groups[group_names[0]]": [
        "node1.in.labs.corp.netin",
        "node2.in.labs.corp.netin"
    ]
```

```
- set_fact:
      groups[group_names[0]]={{ groups[group_names[0]] |
                   map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|list }}
  vars:
    _regex: '^(.*?)\.(.*)$'
    _replace: '-n \1'
```

Hitting the following error line:

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "The variable name 'groups[group_names[0]]' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."}
```

Can i assign back to same list ? after replacing the regex ?
Also -n option is using so that my expected output should be

```
-n node1 -n node2
```

Comment: You added a different problem ``"The variable name 'groups[group_names[0]]' is not valid"``. Delete it and open a  new question instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159207/ansible-use-regex-replace-for-items-in-list-and-assign-it-back

Answer (score 3):

If you're not running Ansible 2.11 or above, the split jinja filter won't work

but you can still do `{{ var.split('-').0 }}` and avoid ugly regexes

Answer (score 1):

Given the data

```yaml
  my_groups:
    group_names:
      - ["node1.in.labs.corp.netin", "node2.in.labs.corp.netin"]
```

the expression below does the job

```yaml
  nodes: "{{ my_groups.group_names.0|map('split', '.')|map('first')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  nodes:
  - node1
  - node2
```

---

The next option is to use *regex_replace*, for example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nodes: "{{ my_groups.group_names.0|
                   map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|list }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '^(.*?)\.(.*)$'
        _replace: '\1'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.  It did not work.  I am using ansible 2.9.27 version .                                                                                    An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: no filter named 'split'

Comment: I see. [split as a function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) is available since 2.11. Are you able to upgrade? The last 3 versions (atm 2.12, 2.11, and 2.10) are supported.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.10 is also fine ? Is there any other way that i could handle in 2.9 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, 2.10 is not enough. When you take a look at the link above you'll see that  ``split`` as a filter was ``New in version 2.11.``

Comment: if i use 2.11 , i get following errors for this piece of code                                                  
        `- name: Copy the ISO to nodes   synchronize:
      src: "{{ iso_location }}"
      dest: "{{ dest_iso_path }}"
      rsync_timeout: 60
`                                                                                                                                          "couldn't resolve module/action 'synchronize'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path

Comment: See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and the part "What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?". I added the *regex_replace* option.

Comment: Added my next try in the question itself. Thank you @vladimir